# Angular.js app not working with CDN

Tags: angularjs

I have checked all the similar questions and found the common issues (Script tags not being closed properly etc) and I cannot find the reason why I'm still getting the "Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." error. Any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="functions.php?action=edituser" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <p>User ID: <span id="userID" ng-model="userid"><?php echo $_GET['userid']; ?></span></p>
            <label>First Name </label><input id="firstname" name="firstname" ng-model="firstName"><br/><br/>
            <label>Last Name </label><input id="lastname" name="lastname" ng-model="lastName"><br/><br/>
            <label>E-mail Address </label><input id="email" name="email" ng-model="email"><br/><br/>
            <label>Cellphone Number </label><input id="cell" name="cell" ng-model="cell"><br/><br/>
            <label>Domain </label><input id="companydomain" name="companydomain" ng-model="companydomain"><br/><br/>
            <label>ID Number </label><input id="said" name="said" ng-model="said"><br/><br/>
            <label>TFA Method </label><select id="tfamethod" name="tfamethod" ng-model="tfamethod">
                <option id="gauth" value="gauth">Google Authenticator</option>
                <option id="sms" value="sms">SMS</option>
                <option id="email" value="email">E-mail</option>
            </select><br/><br/>
            <label>Reset Password? </label><input id="passreset" name="passreset" ng-model="passreset" type="checkbox" value="Expire Password?"/><br/><br/>
        </form>
        <script>
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var response = this.responseText;
            var myObj = JSON.parse(response);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = myObj.firstname;
            $scope.lastName = myObj.lastname;
            $scope.email = myObj.email;
            $scope.cell = myObj.cell;
            $scope.domainname = myObj.domainname;
            $scope.tfamethod = myObj.tfamethod;
            $scope.said = myObj.said;
            });
            }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "functions.php?action=getuserdata&id=" + {{userid}}, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would start by making the HTML valid. Add a head and a body in your HTML. Don't put scripts directly under html. I also have no idea why you define the controller inside the callback of an XHR request.

Comment: {{userid}} not valid javascript simplify this and the code seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/39pqso0b/44/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like @powerfade917 commented the issue that solved my problem.

```
{{userid}} is not valid Javascript and cannot be used in that area, only the app space
```

I removed the variable and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the Angularjs documentation.
[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction)

Add `ng-app="myApp"` in your html / body tag.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```